# Removing floor and make objects fall animation

Tags: animation, rigidbody

I have coins falling into a cube. After a few seconds of them landing I want the 'floor' to move and coins to then fall through down. I have the floor plane set to animate out of the way but the coins just stay where they landed and do not fall down then.

I have tested deleting the floor completely just to see if there was some issue but they fall all the way though then so it must be something to do with the coins after they have initially settled on the plane? Settings below are what I have on the coins.

Any ideas? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at Rigidbody World settings and make sure the frame range extends to the duration you need.

Comment: normally you should apply all rotation and scales...

Comment: for the object called Plane, in your file its Animated option was not activated

Comment: moonboots is right, if you check the animated checkbox of both animated objects and keyframe then on the last animated frame and uncheck and keyframe it one frame later, it works [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wghaB.gif

Comment: moonboots, Bingo! Thanks so much 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just activate the *Animated* option of your floor, otherwise its movement won't be taken into account, only its initial location, and the coins won't fall.